Loading of separate viewers in two different tab screens is not able to initialize second viewer which is under hidden tab
I'm using the react framework and trying to load 2 different models in 2 different viewers at a time. One of the viewers is on the active tab which is rendering and initiating properly but the viewer which is under the hidden tab is not initializing the viewer.
Tried the below approach but failed: As Autodesk.Viewing.The initializer is only being called once despite initializeViewer being executed twice, it may be because the Forge Viewer only initializes once for a given environment. Autodesk's Viewing. Initializer is designed to set up the environment once, and any subsequent calls may not trigger the callback if the environment is already initialized. so initialized another viewer on set timeout as well.
Also tried an approach of display: none and display: block as well but it did not work.

Using the APS Viewer in such setup is tricky. In order to properly instantiate the viewer, you must have a <canvas> in your DOM with non-zero size. In other words, you can't initialize a viewer that's not visible on the page.
What you will probably need to do is create a React wrapper for the viewer, initialize the GuiViewer3D object as part of componentDidMount, and tear it down as part of componentWillUnmount. We have a blog post that provides some suggestions as to how that could be done: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/building-simple-react-wrapper-viewer.
